# Серверный рендеринг на ASP.NET Core и Angular4

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net-core, angular4

Мне необходимо создать сайт на ASP.NET Core и Angular4 с серверным рендерингом , правильно ли я понимаю, что это проект на ASP.NET Core у которого на стороне бекенда просто прикручен angular (а не идет как отдельное приложение). И при создание проекта достаточно выбрать шаблон Angular.

Comment: Неправильно)) Тебе нужно ставить ноду , настраивать ssr, а из asp.net кидать локальные запросы отрендеренного контента

Comment: Не претендую на истину, но если asp.net может исполнять js (к примеру для php есть phpv8js), то можно будет решить без ноды